# Why is macOS still using the system-ruby and not my homebrew-version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, homebrew

I want to get rid of the system-version of Ruby and instead manage ruby-versions via Homebrew.

However, although I followed instructions, `whereis` is still listing the system ruby version and ignores my $PATH.

```
❯ echo $PATH
/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/Users/myuser/..
```

As shown above, the bin-folder of homebrew is first place in my $PATH.

But executing `ruby -v` is showing the builtin-version from macOS and `whereis` confirms:

```
❯ whereis ruby
ruby: /usr/bin/ruby /opt/homebrew/share/man/man1/ruby.1
```

Surprisingly, the MAN-files are part of homebrew, the binary not.

How can I fix that and tell macOS to use my Homebrew based version of Ruby?

Comment: `whereis` might be misleading as it searches standard paths first. Try `whereis -a ruby` to list all binaries or better yet `which ruby` to find the binary that `ruby` will invoke.

Comment: BTW, [`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) / [`chruby`](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) / [`rvm`](https://rvm.io/) might be better alternatives to manage Ruby versions, especially if you want the option to have multiple Ruby versions installed.

Comment: "I want to get rid of the system-version of Ruby" – That's not a good idea. The system version of Ruby, as the name implies is there *for the system* to use. There may be internal macOS tools which use it, for example. Or App Store apps.

Comment: Your PATH looks wrong. It should proably have `/opt/homebrew/bin` in it rather than `/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin` although I don't use Ruby.

Comment: Agree with @Stefan Using rvm or rbenv would be better.